# How to exit "repeat until loop" in fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have defined two 2D arrays `h` and `hh`.I want to assign `hh` with new values. For a specific `k'`, I want `hh(k',j)=1`, if the condition

```
h(k',j)>0
```

is true; and once the condition is false, i.e., `h(k',j')<0`, then for any `j>j'`, `hh(k',j)=0`. I used the following `DO WHILE` loop:

```
  do k=1, npair
    do j =1, movie
      hh(k,j)=0.0
    enddo
  enddo

  do k=1, npair
    do j =1, nmovie
       do while (h(k,j)>0)
         hh(k,j)=h(k,j)
       enddo
    enddo
```

But if the condition `(h(k,j)>0)` is always true, there will be a infinite loop! Could you please suggest how can implement it?

Comment: Will `h` ever change? Why not loop over hh and set the value once and for all?

Comment: @Ross `h` will not change. I want to obtain `hh` by the value of `h` according to the condition. Excuse me, but could you explain what loop over `hh` mean here?

Comment: See my answer below, but 'looping over' a 2D array involves two do loops. Inside both loops, you can do things with `hh(k,j)` that will eventually be done for every possible `k` and `j` combination.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can set each value of `hh` given the value of `h`. I'm also assuming `hh` and `h` are the same size. So you should `do` something for each element in hh. I recommend the following:

```
do k=1,N1    ! N1 and N2 are the limits of the hh and h array.
   do j=1,N2
      if ( h(k,j) > 0) then    ! Check the condition for a specific element in h
         hh(k,j) = 1
      else
         ! -- We need to set *all* values in the desired range
         hh(k,j:N2) = 0

         ! -- And we need to stop loop from overwriting values hh(k,j+1), for example
         ! -- So we break out of the j loop
         exit
      endif
   enddo
enddo
```

You should check to make sure this does what you think it will. Note that I'm using colon notation to assign a range of values in the hh array.
Also, you're unclear on what happens if `h(k,j)` is 0 exactly.

Comment: It is exactly what I want to do. The `if` statement avoids the infinite loop.  Thanks.@Ross.