# How to terminate a do loop?

Tags: loops, fortran, gfortran

I am writing a very basic Fortran Code to create the Ising model. However, I am stuck at the very last step - repeat the calculation until the most stable condition is achieved.

```
do
!Calculation (omitted here)
!Making a decision
if (E1 /= -64) then             !not yet stable
    if(dE > 0.0) then       
    call seed
    call random_number(prob)        ! random generate a number which is 0 <= Prob <= 1      
    Print *, prob
        if(Prob < exp(-dE/T)) then
                        !do nothing as the flip was made
        else
        mat(b,c) = -mat(b,c)        !flip the sign back, i.e. reject the change; only accept with probability of exp(-dE/T)
        end if
    else
    end if                  !Since the sign has changed already, if dE<0, the move must be accepted. Therefore no additional move should be taken
else
end do
end if
end do
```

Apparently, Fortran doesn't like the second last `end do` statement as I didn't defined `do` at that particularly. All I want is to exit the `do` loop once `E1 == -64`.

Comment: I think you have worse problems than mismatching `do` and `end do`.  The variable `E1` is not updated inside the loop, nor anywhere else that is obvious in your code snippet, so there is no way that the result of `E1 /= -64` will ever change.  It also seems rather wonky to have `else` followed immediately by `end if` -- there's no need for the `else` at all if there are no statements between that and `end if`.  Sit back, sketch out the logic of your code, *indent consistently to reveal the logical structure of your code*, and try again.

Comment: Did you want `exit` instead of the first `end do`? Be sure to use indentation to clearly visualize the code blocks.

Comment: @VladimirF You are an absolute LEGEND!! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 10):

In Fortran you can exit a do loop at any time using the `exit` statement.

```
  do
    ...
    if (condition) exit
  end do
```

If your do loop is labelled, use the label in the exit statement too

```
outer: do
  inner: do
    ...
    if (condition) exit outer
  end do inner
end do outer
```

Fortran 2008 allows the exit statement for other constructs too.

Comment: I didn't find any good duplicate except this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272165/how-to-exit-repeat-until-loop-in-fortran . Feel free to find some and close.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a while loop.

```
while (E1 [.ne. OR /=] -64) do
   [your code]
end do
```

This requires `E1` be updated inside the loop. Without this update, `E1` will always not equal -64 and cause an infinite loop. Your code doesn't explicitly show this happening. I assume it does, but it's something to keep in mind.